# Access GTM google tag manager variables from outside of GTM?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I was reading about GDPR and GTM here https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/gdpr-cookie-consent-notification-with-google-tag-manager/

basically how to make GTM gdpr valid.

the issue I saw, was that I don't know how to read any GTM variables from outside of GTM. E.g. in that guide, they store a variable or function that will figure if consent was given or not. How can I read, utilize functions and react to events from outside of GTM?

say I run my little javascript file `myapp.js` on the page. In there I want to for example not add youtube video embeds in case of they have not given consent. Or add videos and share links if they gave consent. This is not something I can do via GTM obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Well the dataLayer variable is public so you can read it at any time it just might be a little hard to find an specific value since you need to move though an array.

Comment: I dont see the variables at all in `dataLayers`. Do you see them?

Comment: Ones GTM is implemented you can just call dataLayer and it ll return an array of JSON objects. The only thing you need to do is itterate over this searching for the "KEY" that has the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a javascript variable on your site as a GTM variable then the variable needs to have global and not local scope (the dataLayer is global but you need to perform a dataLayer.push() to add items to the array).

If the javascript variable on the site is responsible for other site functions and has global scope, then either reference it using a GTM javascript variable or custom javascript variable and use it to act as the trigger exception.

The alternative is to have the site logic prevent the GTM snippet from loading. In the GDPR perfect world, you would have granular opt-out depending on the tags in GTM. You could create a form on site with opt-outs for specific tags, however, that data needs to be stored per customer and delivered to the dataLayer to perform tag specific opt-out functionality.

Can you expand on the logic you are attempting to reference from the site?